# IPV6 Google App Engine

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, dns, ipv6

I'm developing a mobile app using Google App Engine as backend. 
I submitted the app to Apple's review and they rejected my app because it doesn't work with IPv6.

Looking around, I found this website that does some checks about your IPv6 compliance: http://ready.chair6.net/?url=meetfloor-test.appspot.com

As you can see, there are some warnings. 
How can I make my backend IPv6 compliant?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Your site passes better than www.apple.com: http://ready.chair6.net/?url=www.apple.com

Comment: Ops! There's nothing to see here. This isn't about your backend, it's about your iOS application.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers guys! I'm going to take a deeper look on the iOS app and I will post the result

Answer (score 0):

https://support.google.com/a/answer/112038?hl=en

please check this. if you use ghs46.googlehosted.com to set up your custom domain, your backend will work both in v4 and v6.